# Analytical solution to piecewise Poisson equation in 1D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like help solving the following analytically

$$\frac{\partial^2 u(x)}{\partial x^2} = - p(x)$$

where $ p(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       3 & : 0 < x  < 0.4\\
       x & : 0.5 < x < 1\\
       0 & : else
     \end{cases}
   $

and $u(0) = u(1) = 0$

Im stuck on this I have googled, and looked at textbooks, but what I would like is a worked example.
(not homework per se, something I need to understand before I attempt the homework!)

Comment: Notice that $\delta x$ differs from $\partial x$.  I changed it.  I also changed "array" to "cases", which is simpler code and in some cases yields better-looking results.

Comment: Is $p$ really not prescribed on $[0.4,0.5]$?

Comment: Try to consider both cases seperately and work on the output to get $u$ continous.

Comment: @mrf sorry, edited, its 0 on [0.4, 0.5]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the approach using [Green's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green's_function) $G(x,y)$, which by definition is the solution of $-u''=\delta_y$ with zero boundary values, where $y\in (0,1)$ is fixed and $\delta_y$ is the [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function). The presence of $\delta_y$ says that $u'(y+)-u'(y-)=-1$, and $u'$ is piecewise constant elsewhere. Hence,
$$u(x)=\begin{cases} ax,\quad &x<y \\ (a-1)(x-1), \quad &x>y\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
Since we don't want discontinuities in $u$ (they would contribute $\delta'_y$ to $u''$, which is a higher order singularity than we want), we must have $ay=(a-1)(y-1)$. The only solution is $a=1-y$. Thus, 
$$G(x,y)=\begin{cases} (1-y)x,\quad &x<y \\ y(1-x), \quad &x>y\end{cases}\tag{2}$$
or in more compact (and obviously *symmetric*) form, 
$$G(x,y)=\min(x,y)-xy\tag{3}$$
This is how  $G(x,1/3)$ looks:
[image: Green's function]

Returning to the general problem $-u''=p$, we can now write down its solution at once:
$$
u(x)=\int_0^1 G(x,y)\,p(y)\,dy \tag{4}
$$

To evaluate the integral (4) for the function in your example, you should consider the cases $x\le 0.4$, $0.4\le x\le 0.5$ and $x\ge 0.5$ separately.

If $x\le 0.4$: 
$$u(x)=\int_0^{x} y(1-x)\,3\,dy + \int_x^{0.4} x(1-y)\,3\,dy + \int_{0.5}^1 x(1-y)\,y\,dy \tag{5}$$

If $0.4\le x\le 0.5$: 
$$u(x)=\int_0^{0.4} y(1-x)\,3\,dy + \int_{0.5}^1 x(1-y)\,y\,dy \tag{6}$$

If $x\ge 0.5$: 
$$u(x)=\int_0^{0.4} y(1-x)\,3\,dy + \int_{0.5}^x y(1-x)\,y\,dy+\int_{x}^1 x(1-y)\,y\,dy \tag{7}$$

And this is the graph of the solution: 
[image: solution]

Note that it is concave, and flat between $0.4$ and $0.5$ as it should be.

Comment: When your integrating over y in the very last expression, how do you choose where x < y or x > y?

Comment: @user57142 To integrate a piecewise defined function, you split the integral accordingly. For example, if $p(x)= x^2$, then $$u(x)=\int_0^x y(1-x)\,y^2\,dy + \int_x^1 x(1-y)\,y^2\,dy$$ which comes out to $u(x)=(x-x^4)/12$.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, so for my example above, with piecewise defined p(x), the integral would become $u(x)=\int_0^{0.4} y(1-x)\,3\,dy + \int_{0.5}^1 y(1-x)\,x\,dy + \int_{0.4}^1 x(1-y)\,3\,dy + \int_{0.5}^1 x(1-y)\,x\,dy$ ?

Comment: @user57142 That does not look right to me. I added this detail to my answer.

Comment: I evaluated the expression you gave, does u(x) not have to be continious?

Comment: @user57142 I indeed had an error in the integrals, same that you made above. Note that we integrate $G(x,y)p(y)$, not $G(x,y)p(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

@5pm's answer using Green's functions is quite nice of course, and generalizes well to higher dimensions and infinite domains. But in 1D, you can get the solution simply by integrating twice. Observe that
$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}u'(x)=u''(x),$$
so we integrate once from $0$ to $x$ to get
$$u'(x)-u'(0)=\int_0^xu''(t)\,\mathrm dt=-\int_0^xp(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$
Let $q(x)=\int_0^xp(t)\,\mathrm dt$, which you can evaluate analytically. This gives $u'(x)=u'(0)-q(x)$. Now $u'(0)$ is unknown, but no matter; we just integrate again to get
$$u(x)-u(0)=\int_0^xu'(t)\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^x\big(u'(0)-q(t)\big)\,\mathrm dt=u'(0)x-\int_0^xq(t)\,\mathrm dt.$$
Again, let $r(x)=\int_0^xq(t)\,\mathrm dt$. We obtain $u(x)=u(0)+u'(0)x-r(x)$. Applying the boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$ allows us to solve for $u'(0)$, because $r$ is known already:
$$0=u(1)=u(0)+u'(0)\cdot1-r(1)=u'(0)-r(1).$$
Therefore $u'(0)=r(1)$ and the solution is
$$u(x)=r(1)x-r(x).$$